# Enlive Tutorial Issues

Tags: clojure

This is a case of a failure to launch. Namely I am attempting to work through the Enlive tutorial, but have run into the following issue of FileNotFoundException while typing `(load "tutorial/scrape1")` into the REPL.

I am using the following dependencies

```
:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
              [enlive "1.1.1"]]
```

I do the classic steps of `lein deps` then open the REPL and typing the aforementioned line as the tutorial asks. This is all part of the "Your First Scrape with Enlive..." section of https://github.com/swannodette/enlive-tutorial

Comment: is there a directory called `tutorial` (perhaps under the `src` directory), with a file called `scrape1.clj` in it?

Comment: Yes, I was able to find the tutorial under `src`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well that are not the only dependencies you need to add to your `project.clj`. This file needs to look like:

```
(defproject enlive-tutorial "0.1.0"
  :description "Enlive Tutorial"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
                 [enlive "1.1.1"]
                 [ring "1.2.0"]
                 [net.cgrand/moustache "1.1.0"]])
```

So running `lein deps` will cause in a long term of downloading dependencies. After this you can just start with the tutorial as presented in the link you just posted.

Maybe it is a good idea just to clone the git repository and follow the instructions they give you to start coding with it:

```
  1. git clone git://github.com/swannodette/enlive-tutorial.git
  2. cd enlive-tutorial
  3. lein deps
  4. lein repl
```